# unable to create txt record using amazon route 53

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I can't add the following TXT record to my Route 53 DNS config:

```
v=msv1 t=whatever
```

Doing so produces the following error:

> The record set could not be saved because:
>   - The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.

If I do just v=msv1 I get the same thing. Doesn't even seem to work without the v=.

Maybe the t is supposed to go in the Name field and the v is supposed to go in the Value field?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the Route 53 admin page when adding a TXT record set:

```
A text record. Enter multiple values 
    on separate lines. Enclose text in 
    quotation marks.
Example: 
    "Sample Text Entries" 
    "Enclose entries in quotation marks"
```

Comment: If you're creating a TXT record for DKIM on Google Apps for Domains like I was, it worked for me to wrap the entire block in a set of quotes (not separate quotes for each portion of the record.)

Comment: While you enter it into Route 53 as a "single" TXT record, it is served as multiple TXT answers in a DNS query, as you would expect. Wish AWS made that more clear in their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the API or Ansible Route53 module, and you need to set the value on separated lines (e.g. SPF + domain verification).
For instance:

```
"v=spf1 include:mail.zendesk.com ?all"
"google-site-verification=
rXOxyZounnZasA8Z7oaD3c14JdjS9aKSWvsR1EbUSIQ"
```

Then the value should look like:

For API:

`'"v=spf1 include:mail.zendesk.com ?all" "google-site-verification=
rXOxyZounnZasA8Z7oaD3c14JdjS9aKSWvsR1EbUSIQ"'`

From AWS Route53 doc:

> [A TXT record contains a **space-separated** list of double-quoted strings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#TXTFormat)

For Ansible:

`'"v=spf1 include:mail.zendesk.com ?all", "google-site-verification=
rXOxyZounnZasA8Z7oaD3c14JdjS9aKSWvsR1EbUSIQ"'`

> [Multiple **comma-spaced** values are allowed for non-alias records.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/route53_module.html)

BTW: you can verify the validity of your SPF record using a tool like [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx).

Cheers,
Mickael